# jQuery Plugin for Twitter like @ Suggest Dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin recommendation that is similar to what Twitter is using.

Twitter.com, type something and then type, @aTwitterHandle, you get the twitter follwers in a suggestion list under the input box and when you click or return on one of the suggestions, it enters that user handle in the input box.

Any popular plugins that achieve this?  thanks

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Comment: @Gazler, thanks that make sense. The challenge is more around only SHOWING the autocomplete box when a condition is met, like the @ is entered with a space before it. Does that make sense? Thoughts>

Answer (score 0):

I may be 5 years too late, but it looks like [Mentionator](https://github.com/klawson88/Mentionator) is  exactly what you are looking for (or more appropriately, what you *were* looking for): it is a jQuery plug-in which enables clients to create highlighted references to ("mentions") to predefined entities in text areas.

It actually builds upon the functionality of jQuery Autocomplete UI, the very widget which Gazler suggested to you.

I should "mention" one last thing: it is maintained by yours truly :) .